# How to check last access ClearCase vob?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, vob

Can anyone help me how to find time and date when the ClearCase (UCM) VOBS are last accessed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember using [`cleartool lshistory`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm) to check the last events date occurred on a vob.

Something like:

```
cleartool lshis -fmt "%Xn\t%Sd\t%e\t%h\t%u \n" -since 01-Oct-2015 -all <vobname>| grep -v lock | head -1 | grep -o '20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
```

That would give the events on the last 6 months (like "create version", "create branch", ...).
If there are none, the VOB has not been accessed recently (and I then consider archiving it).

This apply for any VOB (UCM or non-UCM).

Answer (score 1):

'lshistory' will certainly give you the most recent change to the PVOB.  If you are interested in the last-accessed time, you can look at the DB files for the PVOB.  For instance,

```
% ls -ltur <pathname_to_VOB_storage_directory>/db
```

That will sort by last-accessed-time of each file and the latest of those files, which would be the last listed because of the '-tr' flags, should include the time close to the last time the PVOB was accessed.  For example:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 vob_owner  vob_group   94830592 Mar 28  2016 vob_db.d05
```

This PVOB was last accessed on March 28, 2016.